# How to solve comiler error: 'v_bias' is not a namespace-name

Tags: c++, g++, libraries

**Sort briefing what I am trying to do:**

I want to use [vnode-lp](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~nedialk/vnodelp/) on my windows PC. I’ve installed MinGW. I’ve installed the necessary dependencies like LAPACK & BLAS libraries as well as Profil/BIAS. The installation of all libraries passed the `make` and `make install` process without errors. I hope (!) I’ve managed to install it correctly.

**Now the Problem:**

Now I’ve tried to get a simple program compiled with basically northing in it just an #include “vnode.h”. First I tried it with Microsoft Visual Studio. Since this gave me several errors I tried to compile it with g++ using MinGW. This gives me the same errors. It starts with

```
./matrix.w:90:17: error: ‘v_bias’ is not a namespace-name
```

**The Question:**

How to include vnodelp into an c++ program and compile it without errors under windows, am I missing something?

Off-topic:

I am trying to get this running for over a week now and don’t know what to do anymore.

Comment: You seem to try to compile c++ code as c code.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a C++ package, I checked it's documentation. The question is how do you compile it?

Comment: The very first text on the linked page says "VNODE-LP is a C++ package". C++ is not C.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I am new to non MSVS-compilers and mess up the gcc and g++ part. Also I was kind of unspecific about the c++ part. I have updated my question and hopefully improved it. First I have used a simple c++ program with a precompiled header in MSVS using the Visual c++ compiler. I only added the include file for vnodelp into the code. Since this gave me the above mentioned errors I tried the gcc (shame on me) as well as the g++ compiler. All 3 same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to finally solve this issue. In case someone has the same problem here is the solution.

I have missed something in the call. Here is the full call that has worked for me:

`g++ -o2 –Wall –Wno-deprecated –DNDEBUG – DPROFIL_VNODE – DMAXORDER=50 –I(path to profil bias)/include –I(path to profil bias)/include/BIAS –I(path to profil bias)/src/Base –I(path to vnodelp)/FADBAD++ -I../include –DNDEBUG –c –o (filename).o (filename).cc`

`g++ -L(path to profil bias)/lib –L(path to lapack)/lib –L../lib –o (filename) (filename).o –lvnode –lProfil –lBias –llr (path to lapack)/lib/liblapack.lib (path to lapack)/lib/libblas.lib –lstd++`

*funfact:*

*This also complies with gcc instead of g++*

Answer (score 1):

C++ is most definitely not C, and packages designed for C++ will never compile and run as C code. So, what you're trying to do really can't be done unless you do some fancy stuff by creating a .dll or something like that, and even then I think you wouldn't get the functionality you want. Why not write your code in C++ and compile with g++ or a similar compiler?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I’ve used the Visual c++ compiler. I’ve also used the gcc (shame on me) and the g++ compiler. All gave me the mentioned errors.